# Use Symfony session component but without framework

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symofny components in the 4th version, but not all framework.
I have Kernel where I implement `HttpKernelInterface` and use Request object from the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation` package.

In the handle methods I'd like to use sessions (also symfony). 
When I try to start session I have an error that native php session is working.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\PhpBridgeSessionStorage;

final class Kernel implements HttpKernelInterface
{
 public function handler(Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
 {
   //Case one
   $session = new Session(); 
   $session->start();//throw error
   // Case two
   $session = new Session(new PhpBridgeSessionStorage());
   $session->start(); //is working, but use native php sessions
 }
}
```

When i use `PhpBridgeSessionStorage` it is working well, but it use native php session, native session ID.

How can I eliminate native sessions in this case without remove it from the php.ini file. I have a few virtual hosts what need it.

Thanks for any hints.

---

Edit:

I did 
`php_value session.auto_start 1` in the htacces.
and moved `new Session()` above `Request::createFromGlobals()`
in this case Request throw the same error.
When I try call to the   `$request->getSession()` it returns null.

Any ideas what I can do to use Symfony sessions?

Comment: If I understand correctly and you have apache then in `.htaccess` for the dir use `php_value session.auto_start 0` maybe.

Comment: It is not working. But I also tested disabled auto start in the php.ini. Also throw error. I think that problem is in the Request object. This object init session. When I set new session before request, then request object throw error that session exists. But this is weird, because when I try to call `$request->getSession()` it returns `null`.